# Access error in pyrebase realtime database subcollection, accessing with user uid

Tags: python-3.x, firebase, firebase-authentication, pyrebase, unauthorizedaccessexcepti

I'm having a problem when I access my realtime database. I'm using Pyrebase5 to access my database. I auth my sistem:

```py
_config = {'example': 'ThisConfig'}
_firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(self._config)
_auth = _firebase.auth()
_user = _auth.sign_in_with_email_and_password('eletroinformaticabrasil.bav.py@mail.com', 'myexample_password')
_db = _firebase.database().child('eletroinformaticabrasil')
_get = _db.child('AUTH_USER').get(token=_user['idToken'])
```

> Errno 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: [https://dazzrickprogrammer-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/eletroinformaticabrasil/AUTH_USER.json?auth=**token**]](https://dazzrickprogrammer-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/eletroinformaticabrasil/AUTH_USER.json?auth=**token**%5D) {     "error" : "Permission denied"   }

My rules:

[image: My rules]

My database:

[image: My datbase]

My authenticator API:

[image: Auth API]

I don't know why its happening, when I use the firebase api in javascript with CDN, I don't have problems.

**EDITED**

I change some things, I don't know what, but I know that the error changed. Now my error is it:

> [db] -> 2023/5/20 - 11:11:52 -> DataSource Get Error   :Exception: [Errno 401 Client Error: Unauthorized for url: https://dazzrickprogrammer-default-rtdb.firebaseio.com/AUTH_GROUP.json?auth=**token**] {     "error" : "Permission denied"   }      Parameters: {|"collection": "AUTH_GROUP"|}

I noted that the address don't go to the eletroinformaticabrasil link, but I change a child to the right link. I will revise my code, I think that is some method that I wrong the call.

** Solved! **

Really I don't know alright what I do, but the last problem is because when is called child() with more than one argument, the childs before is ignored. What I needed is only add the 'eletroinformaticabrasil' like the fist argument.

The fist problem I think that is because before the fist edit of this post, I forgeted to pass the token argument. Thank you @FrankVanPuffelen, your [site](https://jwt.io/) help me so much.

Comment: If you stuff that value from `**token**` into a site like jwt.io, you can see what information is in it. If you check the `user_id` value in there, does it match with the `ZuA...` value you check in your rules?

Comment: Yes, user id: "user_id": "AuAlZ6OuGwQ0UknHHpaqFdFhXvh1"

Comment: Are you sure you get back a `401` code from Firebase? Firebase would usually respond with a `403` when the permission is denied by your security rules.

Comment: Yes, my code create a debug file, when try to accend in the database and receive a error, it write the error in a file and give me the parameters. Realy is it the problem that I receive. Know I change a thing and the problem change. I will edit my question.

Answer (score 1):

If the sign-in successfully completed, it seems most likely that the UID of the user you signed in with doesn't match the `ZuA...` value you check in your rules.

If you take tghe `**token**` from the error message, you can pass that into a site like jwt.io to decode it and see what information is in it. If you check the `user_id` value in the decoded info, is has to match the value that your rules check for.

---

Here is one example of an ID token from Firebase you can use to test with:

```js
eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImQwZTFkMjM5MDllNzZmZjRhNzJlZTA4ODUxOWM5M2JiOTg4ZjE4NDUiLCJ0eXAiOiJKV1QifQ.eyJwcm92aWRlcl9pZCI6ImFub255bW91cyIsImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vc2VjdXJldG9rZW4uZ29vZ2xlLmNvbS9kYmxhdGVuY3kiLCJhdWQiOiJkYmxhdGVuY3kiLCJhdXRoX3RpbWUiOjE2NTE0MzgyMjAsInVzZXJfaWQiOiJWTWdVY2x2NzI2UFlpVXhKTmxXR2RMYmZEN2syIiwic3ViIjoiVk1nVWNsdjcyNlBZaVV4Sk5sV0dkTGJmRDdrMiIsImlhdCI6MTY4NDUzNjkxMCwiZXhwIjoxNjg0NTQwNTEwLCJmaXJlYmFzZSI6eyJpZGVudGl0aWVzIjp7fSwic2lnbl9pbl9wcm92aWRlciI6ImFub255bW91cyJ9fQ.Oq8psO47h0DUjD08qYZJF6k7HVOAFkSqhpwaey8tbuKcyf5_0YcHD25oz8RS5qaj2RIPVtpUnPnvrOic2Bt7aSfvvfbUS7wzWG61BHxUDjR4CTxuaK6a5AWiR6jsYcOxStxN_q6enCwbSzj0Md2sXgNsPLz15l4Vbcg678w8lDaW2VFp28gjgQufnXQ0iT2FVZxo_ntk00LylDpaLEOR6c_P2f_8CJOomTZ709POae3ZmoVlbgiqjp22Ap8c6YCMGf7STeclIWAarj_U1t4VPJUYCl4TjARTnx-lSJWGMI-vc2mGfmHmm-RhSnZXgwkky6ninvUWBvus6aAsSbjfNA
```

If you paste this value into jwt.io, you should see that the `user_id` field shows `VMgUclv726PYiUxJNlWGdLbfD7k2`.

Comment: I tried it that you said, but I receive the right uid code. If you want, I can give you the token, maybe it help.